# Create an Open/Closed store based on time records with html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an Open/Closed store based on time records with html and JavaScript.

so if it's Friday the div that have an `id="friday"` will be shown, else the div with id="week" is shown.

also the time if its from 8 am to 6pm the div with `id="open"` will show else the div with `id="closed"` will shown

I create this code, but I doses not work properly I don't know what's the problem.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();

function openClose() {
  if (currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 6) {
    document.getElementById("friday").style.display = "none";
    if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour <= 18) {
      document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  if (currentDay === 7) {
    document.getElementById("week").style.display = "none";
    if (currentHour >= 10 && currentHour <= 17) {
      document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  if (currentDay === 0) {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("friday").style.display = "none";
  }
};

setInterval(openClose(), 5000);
```

```html
<div ALIGN="center">
    <div style="color:red;font-size: 25px;" id="closed"> Closed</div>
    <div style="color:green;font-size: 25px;" id="open">Open.</div>
</div> 
<time> We are open every day of the week - 
    <div id="friday"> Friday - 8:00 AM to 5:30 PM</div> 
    <div id="week">8:00 AM to 5:00 PM</div> 
</time>
```

Comment: setInterval expects function as first argument so you are passing the result of function invocation instead you just have to pass function reference `setInterval( openClose, 5000 );`

Comment: Be careful of timezones.  Because `Date` is going to give you time in the timezone of the browser, someone outside of your timezone may see the open/close sign at the wrong time.  Looks like @decpk sees what is likely the first big issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following slightly shorter script should do the trick:

The constant `time` holds the current time information as valid in a given time zone in numeric form. This makes it easy to decide whether the shop is "open" or "closed". A similar process is used for the decision whether we have a "normal weekday", a Friday ("Fri") or a Sunday ("Sun"), based on the string-value in the constant `day`.

```js
  
function openClose() {
  const [day,t] = new Date().toLocaleString('en-en', {weekday:"short",hour: '2-digit',minute:'2-digit', hour12: false, timeZone: 'Europe/London' }).replace(":","").split(" "),
         time = +t; // make time numeric
  document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(d=>d.style.display=""); // make all divs visible at first
  document.getElementById(day!=="Fri"?"friday":"week").style.display = "none";
  // console.log(time);
  document.getElementById(time>=(day==="Sun"?1000:800) && time<=(day==="Fri"?1730:1700)?"closed":"open").style.display = "none";
}
      
setInterval(openClose, 5000);
openClose();
```

```html
<div ALIGN="center">
    <div style="color:red;font-size: 25px;" id="closed"> Closed</div>
    <div style="color:green;font-size: 25px;" id="open">Open.</div>
</div> 
<time> We are open every day of the week - 
    <div id="friday"> Friday - 8:00 AM to 5:30 PM</div> 
    <div id="week">8:00 AM to 5:00 PM</div> 
</time>
```

I am using `Date.toLocaleString()` to get the current date and time in the specified timezone (here: "Europe/London") with daylight-saving-time adjustments, if applicable.

The script will keep checking the weekday and time in intervals of 5 seconds and will show or hide the appropriate `<div>`s, taking care of the varying opening times on Fridays and Sundays. This is not really "efficient", as changes will happen very rarely, but it will work in a way, that always the up-to-date opening information will be displayed.

Although `day` and `time` appear to be *changing* over time, they are assigned only *once* within the scope of the function `openClose()` and are for this reason `const` values there.